# Displaying the text file data in dictionary format

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file(new.txt) which has data like:

```
{
    "String1": {
        "Value1": {"One":"a","Two":"b","Three":"c"},
        "Value2": {"One":"aa","Two":"bb","Three":"cc"},
         }

     "String2": {
         "Value1": {"One":"a1","Two":"b1","Three":"c1"},
         "Value2": {"One":"aa1","Two":"bb1","Three":"cc1"},
         }
}
```

I want to display the value of:
String1,value1 that is {"One":"a","Two":"b","Three":"c"} 
String2,value2 and One that is "aa1"

How can i display it..

Comment: In the 5th line after `}`, there should be a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import ast
with open('new.txt') as f:
    d = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
print d['String2']['Value2']['One']
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without ast?

Comment: @SuryaGupta - with `eval`, but you don't want to use it.

Comment: @eumiro: The Data neither seems to be valid json or valid Python Object form

Answer (score 1):

It looks like json,  but missing a few important parts. compare with below,  missing a few ","'s .  Is it copy paste of new.txt or some manual format error?

```
{
    "String2": {
        "Value2": {
            "Three": "cc1", 
            "Two": "bb1", 
            "One": "aa1"
        }, 
        "Value1": {
            "Three": "c1", 
            "Two": "b1", 
            "One": "a1"
        }
    }, 
    "String1": {
        "Value2": {
            "Three": "cc", 
            "Two": "bb", 
            "One": "aa"
        }, 
        "Value1": {
            "Three": "c", 
            "Two": "b", 
            "One": "a"
        }
    }
}
```

If it should be json, it's pretty easy to handle with python:

```
import json
with open('new.txt') as f:
    myjson = json.loads(f.read())
print myjson['String2']['Value2']['One']
```

ast import in eumiro answer look pretty nifty though.